# WPF ListView Show selected item

Tags: wpf, listview, selecteditem

I want to show the selected item in a list view automatically(it isn't possible to show all items without scrolling).

`this.listView.SelectedIndex = 999;` selects of course an item, but it doesn't show it.

what can I use to show it automatically ?

kind regards, jeff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this one:
[Scroll WPF Listview to specific line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211971/scroll-wpf-listview-to-specific-line)

Answer (score 11):

You can do this:-

> listview.ScrollIntoView(listview.SelectedItem);

[Scroll WPF ListBox to the SelectedItem set in code in a view model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8827489/scroll-wpf-listbox-to-the-selecteditem-set-in-code-in-a-view-model)

Answer (score 3):

**Update 2023 for .NET 5-7**

Install a nuget package [Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf/), create a class like following:

```
using Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows;

public class ScrollToSelectedListBoxItemBehavior: Behavior<ListBox>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged += AssociatedObjectOnSelectionChanged;
        AssociatedObject.IsVisibleChanged += AssociatedObjectOnIsVisibleChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged -= AssociatedObjectOnSelectionChanged;
        AssociatedObject.IsVisibleChanged -= AssociatedObjectOnIsVisibleChanged;
        base.OnDetaching();
    }

    private static void AssociatedObjectOnIsVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ScrollIntoFirstSelectedItem(sender);
    }

    private static void AssociatedObjectOnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ScrollIntoFirstSelectedItem(sender);
    }

    private static void ScrollIntoFirstSelectedItem(object sender)
    {
        if (!(sender is ListBox listBox)) 
            return;
        var selectedItems = listBox.SelectedItems;
        if (selectedItems.Count > 0)
            listBox.ScrollIntoView(selectedItems[0]);
    }
}
```

Moving to the XAML editor we need to add a single line:

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
```

Add this behavior class to `ListView` control:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <local:ScrollToSelectedListBoxItemBehavior />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</ListView>
```

Comment: This works like a charm. The new package for this is `Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf` as the `System.Windows.Interactivity.WPF` is depreciated.

Answer (score -1):

This might help you, i'm not sure if it's what you're looking for but it brings the selected item into view and scrolls to it for you if necessary.

```
 int selectedIndex = listView.Items.IndexOf((listView.SelectedItems[0]))

 listView.Items[selectedIndex].EnsureVisible();
```

Comment: This is a WinForms method , is it not!