# Scroll WPF ListBox to the SelectedItem set in code in a view model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a XAML view with a list box:

```
<control:ListBoxScroll ItemSource="{Binding Path=FooCollection}"
                       SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFoo, Mode=TwoWay}"
                       ScrollSelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFoo}">
    <!-- data templates, etc. -->
</control:ListBoxScroll>
```

The selected item is bound to a property in my view. When the user selects an item in the list box my SelectedFoo property in the view model gets updated. When I set the SelectedFoo property in my view model then the correct item is selected in the list box.

The problem is that if the SelectedFoo that is set in code is not currently visible I need to additionally call `ScrollIntoView` on the list box. Since my ListBox is inside a view and my logic is inside my view model ... I couldn't find a convenient way to do it. So I extended ListBoxScroll:

```
class ListBoxScroll : ListBox
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ScrollSelectedItemProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "ScrollSelectedItem",
        typeof(object),
        typeof(ListBoxScroll),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
            null,
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, 
            new PropertyChangedCallback(onScrollSelectedChanged)));
    public object ScrollSelectedItem
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(ScrollSelectedItemProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ScrollSelectedItemProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void onScrollSelectedChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var listbox = d as ListBoxScroll;
        listbox.ScrollIntoView(e.NewValue);
    }
}
```

It basically exposes a new dependency property `ScrollSelectedItem` which I bind to the `SelectedFoo` property on my view model. I then hook into the property changed callback of the dependent property and scroll the newly selected item into view.

Does anyone else know of an easier way to call functions on user controls on a XAML view that is backed by a view model? It's a bit of a run around to:

1. create a dependent property
2. add a callback to the property changed callback
3. handle function invocation inside the static callback

It would be nice to put the logic right in the `ScrollSelectedItem { set {` method but the dependency framework seems to sneak around and manages to work without actually calling it.

Comment: Will be much easier to set `SelectedIndex`.

Comment: It sounds like a View "concern" rather than a ViewModel one. I've had to do something similar but I left the code in the view. See http://matthamilton.net/focus-a-virtualized-listboxitem

Comment: @MattHamilton - this code is technically in the View (inside a control). What code would you write in a View (anywhere) that would accomplish calling ScrollIntoView? Keep in mind that I can't override the set on SelectedItem since it isn't virtual.

Comment: @anatoliiG - does SelectedIndex cause the view to scroll to the selected item?

Comment: @JamesFassett For `DataGrid` - yes. Unfortunately I've not tried it for `ListBox`.

Comment: @anatoliiG - I just tested it and SelectedIndex does not scroll the ListBox

Answer (score 43, accepted):

After reviewing the answers a common theme came up: external classes listening to the SelectionChanged event of the ListBox. That made me realize that the dependant property approach was overkill and I could just have the sub-class listen to itself:

```
class ListBoxScroll : ListBox
{
    public ListBoxScroll() : base()
    {
        SelectionChanged += new SelectionChangedEventHandler(ListBoxScroll_SelectionChanged);
    }

    void ListBoxScroll_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ScrollIntoView(SelectedItem);
    }
}
```

I feel this is the simplest solution that does what I want.

Honourable mention goes to adcool2007 for bringing up Behaviours. Here are a couple of articles for those interested:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johngossman/archive/2008/05/07/the-attached-behavior-pattern.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/AttachedBehaviors.aspx

I think for generic behaviours that will be added to several different user controls (e.g. click behaviours, drag behaviours, animation behaviours, etc.) then attached behaviours make a lot of sense. The reason I don't want to use them in this particular case is that the implementation of the behaviour (calling `ScrollIntoView`) isn't a generic action that can happen to any control other than a ListBox.

Comment: Simple & effective, may get less attention for not being deeply technical but got my vote :)

Comment: Don't forget to unsubscribe from the event :P

Comment: @adminSoftDK There is no need to unsubscribe from the event. An object listening to its own event can be GC'ed just fine.

Comment: Most simple solution - thank you. I just handle the event in code behind in vb.net  
      `Private Sub anyListBox_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As SelectionChangedEventArgs) Handles anyListBox.SelectionChanged
          sender.ScrollIntoView(sender.SelectedItem)
         End Sub`

Answer (score 59):

Have you tried using Behavior...  Here is a ScrollInViewBehavior. I have used it for ListView and DataGrid..... I thinks it should work for ListBox......

You have to add a reference to    `System.Windows.Interactivity` to use `Behavior<T> class`

## Behavior

```
public class ScrollIntoViewForListBox : Behavior<ListBox>
{
    /// <summary>
    ///  When Beahvior is attached
    /// </summary>
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        this.AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged += AssociatedObject_SelectionChanged;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// On Selection Changed
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    void AssociatedObject_SelectionChanged(object sender,
                                           SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is ListBox)
        {
            ListBox listBox = (sender as ListBox);
            if (listBox .SelectedItem != null)
            {
                listBox.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                    (Action) (() =>
                                  {
                                      listBox.UpdateLayout();
                                      if (listBox.SelectedItem !=
                                          null)
                                          listBox.ScrollIntoView(
                                              listBox.SelectedItem);
                                  }));
            }
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// When behavior is detached
    /// </summary>
    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        this.AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged -=
            AssociatedObject_SelectionChanged;

    }
}
```

## Usage

Add alias to `XAML` as  `xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"`

then in your `Control`

```
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyList}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=MyItem,
                                         Mode=TwoWay}"
                  SelectionMode="Single">
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <Behaviors:ScrollIntoViewForListBox />
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </ListBox>
```

Now When ever "MyItem" property is set in `ViewModel` the List will be scrolled when changes are refelected.

Comment: That is actually pretty cool. It's similar to the attached property approach described by crazyarabian but it feels quite a bit cleaner. With both his attached property solution and your Behaviour solution I would have to write a new class. It just seems to make more sense extending the ListBox control and doing the event handling in the sub-class. I'm going to try that today and see if it is as clean as your behaviour solution.

Comment: @JamesFassett Behavoir is usually used to Give you Control the functionality that it currently does not have.... IE.... to avoid Extending a control....but i believe extending is as good as this..

Comment: Just using the Express version. Does this solution need Blend?

Comment: @paul Its needs a dll from blend Sdk `System.Windows.Interactivity`,also (i am not sure but) thre is not limitaiton for using dlls in express version.

Comment: Neat! Any reason for the 2nd null check on `listBox.SelectedItem` within your BeginInvoke delegate? I'm guessing that SelectedItem has the potential to change since you're kicking off the scroll asynchronously?

Comment: ListBox listBox = (sender as ListBox);  better direct cast it: ListBox listBox = (ListBox)sender; as you alerady checked with 'is' the line before.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. However, I had to set `VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing` = false on my `ListBox` to get it to work consistently.

Comment: As the `System.Windows.Interactivity.WPF` is depreciated, the new package for this is `Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf`

Answer (score 24):

Because this is strictly a View problem, there's no reason you can't have an event handler in the code behind of your view for this purpose. Listen for `ListBox.SelectionChanged` and use that to scroll the newly selected item into view.

```
private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ((ListBox)sender).ScrollIntoView(e.AddedItems[0]);
}
```

You also don't need a derived `ListBox` to do this. Just use a standard control and when the `ListBox.SelectedItem` value changes (as described in your original question), the above handler will be executed and the item will be scrolled into view.

```
    <ListBox
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FooCollection}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedFoo}"
        SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged"
        />
```

Another approach would be to write an attached property that listens for `ICollectionView.CurrentChanged` and then invokes `ListBox.ScrollIntoView` for the new current item. This is a more "reusable" approach if you need this functionality for several list boxes. You can find a good example here to get you started: http://michlg.wordpress.com/2010/01/16/listbox-automatically-scroll-currentitem-into-view/

Comment: I don't mind listening for an event but the activity "scroll to the selected item" really feels like it is part of the control and not the surrounding view.  I could just write the event listener inside of my ListBoxScroll subclass however - and that would get me away from the dependent property callback an into a cleaner event delegate.

Comment: I like this approach but it's a bit cumbersome if you have a number of ListBoxes, I may take this functionality and derive my own ListBox. I agree that it is strictly a View problem and that the code is ok to be in the view...

Comment: @AdriaanDavel just bind all of the ListBox SelectionChanged to the same handler, or maybe you already do that, and are just talking about all the event handler subscription statements being cumbersome?

Answer (score 15):

I'm using this (in my opinion) clear and easy solution

```
listView.SelectionChanged += (s, e) => 
    listView.ScrollIntoView(listView.SelectedItem);
```

where `listView` is name of `ListView` control in xaml, `SelectedItem` is affected from my MVVM and code is **inserted in constructor** in xaml.cs file.

Comment: Simplest solution here. Worked great for me.

Answer (score 13):

I know this is an old question, but my recent search for the same problem has brought me to this. I wanted to use the behavior approach, but didn't want a dependency on the Blend SDK just to give me `Behavior<T>` so here's my solution without it:

```
public static class ListBoxBehavior
{
    public static bool GetScrollSelectedIntoView(ListBox listBox)
    {
        return (bool)listBox.GetValue(ScrollSelectedIntoViewProperty);
    }

    public static void SetScrollSelectedIntoView(ListBox listBox, bool value)
    {
        listBox.SetValue(ScrollSelectedIntoViewProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ScrollSelectedIntoViewProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ScrollSelectedIntoView", typeof (bool), typeof (ListBoxBehavior),
                                            new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnScrollSelectedIntoViewChanged));

    private static void OnScrollSelectedIntoViewChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var selector = d as Selector;
        if (selector == null) return;

        if (e.NewValue is bool == false)
            return;

        if ((bool) e.NewValue)
        {
            selector.AddHandler(Selector.SelectionChangedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(ListBoxSelectionChangedHandler));
        }
        else
        {
            selector.RemoveHandler(Selector.SelectionChangedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(ListBoxSelectionChangedHandler));
        }
    }

    private static void ListBoxSelectionChangedHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(sender is ListBox)) return;

        var listBox = (sender as ListBox);
        if (listBox.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            listBox.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                (Action)(() =>
                    {
                        listBox.UpdateLayout();
                        if (listBox.SelectedItem !=null)
                            listBox.ScrollIntoView(listBox.SelectedItem);
                    }));
        }
    }
}
```

and then usage is just

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyList}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding Path=MyItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
         SelectionMode="Single" 
         behaviors:ListBoxBehavior.ScrollSelectedIntoView="True">
```

Comment: Works very well, I prefer not dragging in that dependency too.

Comment: Shouldn't you remove the `if (e.NewValue is bool == false)` code? If `e.NewValue` becomes false, the handler should be removed no?

Comment: @Ziriax this is a test that the type of e.NewValue is boolean, not that it is false.

Comment: Ouch, I completely misread that, silly me! Another thing I noted: it is very well possible that the `SelectedItem` remains the same, but the `SelectedIndex` changes. For example when using the `ObservableCollection<T>.Move` method, the `SelectedItem` does not change, and the `SelectionChangedEvent` is not fired. So the item will not be moved into-view. So some extra logic needs to be added to deal with this case?

Comment: @Dutts By default, the local namespace is local [xmlns:local="clr-namespace:<yourAssemblyName>", then where "behavior:ListBoxBehavior..." will be "local:ListBoxBehavior.ScrollSelectedIntoView="true" ", antonio

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
private void lstBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    lstBox.ScrollIntoView(lstBox.SelectedItem);
}
```

Comment: That is a solution, but I think the question wanted a solution compatible with the MVVM pattern.

Comment: @user672951 This fits the MVVM pattern just as much as any of the other solutions in this question.

Answer (score 3):

After tying various methods I found the following to be the simplest and the best

```
lstbox.Items.MoveCurrentToLast();
lstbox.ScrollIntoView(lstbox.Items.CurrentItem);
```

Answer (score 2):

I took Ankesh's answer and made it not dependent on the blend sdk. The downside of my solution is that it will apply to all listboxes in your app. But the upside is no custom class needed.

When your app is initializing...

```
    internal static void RegisterFrameworkExtensionEvents()
    {
        EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(ListBox), ListBox.SelectionChangedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(ScrollToSelectedItem));
    }

    //avoid "async void" unless used in event handlers (or logical equivalent)
    private static async void ScrollToSelectedItem(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is ListBox)
        {
            var lb = sender as ListBox;
            if (lb.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                await lb.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate
                {
                    lb.UpdateLayout();
                    if (lb.SelectedItem != null)
                        lb.ScrollIntoView(lb.SelectedItem);
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

This makes all of your listboxes scroll to selected (which I like as a default behavior).