# How to autoscroll to the bottom of datagrid in wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

I have `DataGrid`, which has got 2 modes, `ListView` and `alleryView`. When we select an item in `GalleryView` and switch to `ListView` the same item gets selected in list view too. But scroll does not scrolls down to the selected item automatically. How to make it work automatically?

XAML File

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ListItems}" RowStyle="{StaticResource DataGridRowStyle}"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowHeight="60" CanUserAddRows="False" 
              CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" AlternationCount="2"
              HorizontalGridLinesBrush="LightSteelBlue" VerticalGridLinesBrush="LightSteelBlue"
              SelectionMode="Single" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSearchItem}" 
              IsReadOnly="True" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Once" behaviors:DataGridBehavior.Autoscroll="{Binding Autoscroll}" >
```

CS File

```
     private void SetSelectedItemOnViewChange()
    {
        if (SelectedViewMode.ModeName == ViewModes[1].ModeName)
            GallerySearchResults.SelectedSearchItem = GallerySearchResults.GalleryItems.FirstOrDefault((x => x.IndexNo == SelectedRecordIndex));


        else if (SelectedViewMode.ModeName == ViewModes[0].ModeName)
        {

            ListSearchResults.SelectedSearchItem = ListSearchResults.ListItems.FirstOrDefault((x => x.IndexNum == SelectedRecordIndex));
            if (SelectedRecordIndex > 10)
                Autoscroll = true;
        }

    }
```

Behavior file:

```
     public static class DataGridBehavior
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AutoscrollProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
    "Autoscroll", typeof(bool), typeof(DataGridBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(default(bool), AutoscrollChangedCallback));

    private static readonly Dictionary<DataGrid, NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler> handlersDict = new Dictionary<DataGrid, NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler>();

    private static void AutoscrollChangedCallback(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var dataGrid = dependencyObject as DataGrid;
        if (dataGrid == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Dependency object is not DataGrid.");
        }

        if ((bool)args.NewValue)
        {
            Subscribe(dataGrid);
            dataGrid.Unloaded += DataGridOnUnloaded;
            dataGrid.Loaded += DataGridOnLoaded;
        }
        else
        {
            Unsubscribe(dataGrid);
            dataGrid.Unloaded -= DataGridOnUnloaded;
            dataGrid.Loaded -= DataGridOnLoaded;
        }
    }

    private static void Subscribe(DataGrid dataGrid)
    {
        var handler = new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler((sender, eventArgs) => ScrollToEnd(dataGrid));
        handlersDict.Add(dataGrid, handler);
        ((INotifyCollectionChanged)dataGrid.Items).CollectionChanged += handler;
        ScrollToEnd(dataGrid);
    }

    private static void Unsubscribe(DataGrid dataGrid)
    {
        NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler handler;
        handlersDict.TryGetValue(dataGrid, out handler);
        if (handler == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        ((INotifyCollectionChanged)dataGrid.Items).CollectionChanged -= handler;
        handlersDict.Remove(dataGrid);
    }

    private static void DataGridOnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
    {
        var dataGrid = (DataGrid)sender;
        if (GetAutoscroll(dataGrid))
        {
            Subscribe(dataGrid);
        }
    }

    private static void DataGridOnUnloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
    {
        var dataGrid = (DataGrid)sender;
        if (GetAutoscroll(dataGrid))
        {
            Unsubscribe(dataGrid);
        }
    }

    private static void ScrollToEnd(DataGrid datagrid)
    {
        if (datagrid.Items.Count == 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        datagrid.ScrollIntoView(datagrid.Items[datagrid.Items.Count - 1]);
    }

    public static void SetAutoscroll(DependencyObject element, bool value)
    {
        element.SetValue(AutoscrollProperty, value);
    }

    public static bool GetAutoscroll(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (bool)element.GetValue(AutoscrollProperty);
    }
}
```

xaml.cs file

```
    public partial class ItemGridControl : UserControl
{
    public ItemGridControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

}
```

These are the I am working with. But the changes are not getting reflected. Item is getting selected on switching but the scroll bar is not going to bottom. I want it to go to bottom of the page when item number ie., SelectedRecordIndex is greater than 10

Comment: You can scroll to `SelectedItem` using `dataGrid.ScrollIntoView(dataGrid.SelectedItem)`

Comment: In which file this has to be mentioned?

Comment: In the SetSelectedItemOnViewChange method of your CS file

Comment: Not possible because it is a ViewModel and datagrid object cannot be created there

Comment: I am not writing anything code behind

Comment: Check this out, this might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18019425/scrollintoview-for-wpf-datagrid-mvvm

Comment: You want to scroll to the end or to the selected item of datagrid?

Comment: yes to the end.

Comment: Have you tried keeping breakpoint in AutoscrollChangedCallback method in the behaviour? Is it getting called?

Comment: Yes it is getting called

Comment: Then check if it executing the line `dataGrid.ScrollIntoView(dataGrid.Items[dataGrid.Items.Count - 1]);` and for the correct `DataGrid`. Change you binding for AutoScroll like `behaviors:DataGridBehavior.Autoscroll="{Binding Autoscroll, Mode=TwoWay}"` and make sure you are setting this `AutoScroll` property in your `ViewModel`.

Answer (score 0):

To scroll `DataGrid` to particular row (or column) you can use `DataGrid.ScrollIntoView`, which has two overloads:

`ScrollIntoView(Object)` - scrolls to specified item in datagrid view (i.e. row)

`ScrollIntoView(Object, DataGridColumn)` - scrolls to specified item and column

In your case you rather need first overload. In order oto scroll to last row you could use such code:

```
myDataGrid.ScrollIntoView(myDataGrid.Items[myDataGrid.Items.Count - 1]);
```

Comment: This has to be written code behind.. Is there any method by using ViewModel? Because I don't want to write anything code behind means in xaml.cs file. It is just for initialization

Comment: @user3422209 It is code behind. How would put that code in XAML ??

Comment: Not in XAML... in the CS file... ViewModel.CS.. not in Xaml.cs

Comment: @user3422209 Sorry, but I don't understnad you. THIS IS C# code, NOT XAML. I don't understand where do you have problem.

Comment: I have these file, XAML, XAML.CS and ViewModel.CS.. as mentioned in the question. Only contructor is called in xaml.cs.... In Viewmodel.cs we do the coding

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in the ViewModel you can use a Behaviour.

You can check it in: [Scroll WPF ListBox to the SelectedItem set in code in a view model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8827489/scroll-wpf-listbox-to-the-selecteditem-set-in-code-in-a-view-model/8830961#8830961)

There explains how to do it with a ListBox, it's the same with a DataGrid.