# WP7 - VisualTreeHelper to loop through all ListBox Items

Tags: windows-phone-7

I need to create a new ListBox based on items that are selected (checked). The following code actually worked if I only had like 20 items on the ListBox, but adding more items make it crash. Can anybody know how to make it work, or have a different aproach? Is there a limite for looping through a listBox?

```cs
    // worked fine for 20 items,
    // but my actual list contems 95 items...
    private void btnCreateNewList_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

                int totalItemsCB = ListCheckBoxVocabulary.Items.Count;
                for (int ii = 0; ii < totalItemsCB-1; ii++)
                {
                    ListBoxItem item = this.ListCheckBoxVocabulary.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(ii) as ListBoxItem;
                    CheckBox thisCheckBox = FindFirstElementInVisualTree<CheckBox>(item);
                    if (thisCheckBox.IsChecked == true) 
                    {

                        dataPlayListSource.Add(new SampleData() { Text = thisCheckBox.Content.ToString() + " | " + ii });
                        // this.PlayListCheckBoxVocabulary.UpdateLayout();
                        this.PlayListCheckBoxVocabulary.ItemsSource = dataPlayListSource;
                    }

                }
    }

    private T FindFirstElementInVisualTree<T>(DependencyObject parentElement) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        var count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parentElement);
        if (count == 0)
            return null;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parentElement, i);

            if (child != null && child is T)
            {
                return (T)child;
            }
            else
            {
                var result = FindFirstElementInVisualTree<T>(child);
                if (result != null)
                    return result;

            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

and xaml:

```xml
        <controls:PivotItem Header="Vocabulary" >
            <ListBox x:Name="ListCheckBoxVocabulary" Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <!--<StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17" Width="432">-->
                        <CheckBox x:Name="cbVocabulary" Content="{Binding Text}" Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="UncheckBox" />
                        <!--</StackPanel>-->
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </controls:PivotItem>
```

Comment: what is the exception you are getting?

Comment: Hi,,, I am getting the following: Reference is not a valid visual DependencyObject on the line  var count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parentElement); but it goes through if I have less items on the same list...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list is virtual - controls are created as they are needed and potentially reused (I think).

Your options are to turn the `ListBox` to not be virtualized (override the template, and for the container, instead of a `SerializedStackPanel`, choose a regular `StackPanel`).

Your other (and preferable) option is to do the checking via Data Binding. Way easier and faster in most situations.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but how can I do the checking via Data Biding? You mean like adding items that are clicked to a new listbox? (I tried that, but what if I uncheck an item? How can I an update the listbox? Do you have any sample? I am still confused...

Comment: You are binding {Items} to your ListBox - if each Item had a Boolean that signified whether or not it's checked, you could bind THAT to the Checkbox {IsChecked} dependency property and essentially just have it "work"

Comment: I was trying to understand and work around the problem I found this article: **ListBoxItems are destroyed if they are not within view.** Consequently ContainerFromItem() and ContainerFromIndex() return null since the ListBoxItems do not exist. This is apparently a memory/performance (
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211971/scroll-wpf-listview-to-specific-line). That's exactly what is happening to my code, because if I test it with a few items it works perfeclty well...

Comment: With that in mind I just force a way to view items on the screen using **Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>  { ListCheckBoxVocabulary.SelectedIndex = ii;** I set a sleep thread (for testing) and it worked... I am generating a new ListBox keeping only the contents of checked checkbox (in the listbox)... I could not quite execute what you said, 'cause If I bind the checkboxes the new listbox generated will stay always the same, unckeck won't make a difference. I am going back to it, I must be missing something, thanks.

Comment: Make the checkbox binding TwoWay and then when the user checks the box, your underlying data will change as well.