# How to scroll to the selected row in the grid of listview in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have written a code to switch from list view to gallery view, vice-versa. The item selected in listview gets selected in galleryview too when switched to it and vice-versa. Now when switching to listview the item gets selected but control does not scrolls to that particular row. We have to scroll manually. I want it to be scrolled to the selected row automatically when switched.

```
     private void GallerySearchResults_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (GallerySearchResults.SelectedSearchItem != null)
            SelectedRecordIndex = GallerySearchResults.SelectedSearchItem.IndexNo;

        SelectedSearchItem = GallerySearchResults.SelectedSearchItem; 


    }
    private void ListSearchResults_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        if (ListSearchResults.SelectedSearchItem != null)
            SelectedRecordIndex = ListSearchResults.SelectedSearchItem.IndexNum;
        SelectedSearchItem = ListSearchResults.SelectedSearchItem; 
    }
    private void SetSelectedItemOnViewChange()
    {
        if (SelectedViewMode.ModeName == ViewModes[1].ModeName)
            GallerySearchResults.SelectedSearchItem = GallerySearchResults.GalleryItems.FirstOrDefault((x => x.IndexNo == SelectedRecordIndex));


        else if (SelectedViewMode.ModeName == ViewModes[0].ModeName)
            ListSearchResults.SelectedSearchItem = ListSearchResults.ListItems.FirstOrDefault((x => x.IndexNum == SelectedRecordIndex));

    }
```

Comment: hmm.. seems like a 2 part question you're asking here. 1. does a `ListView` support scrolling to the selected `ListItemView`, 2. if so, "what am I doing wrong or what should I do here?"; if not, "what can I do to implement this behavior".. is that about right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scroll WPF Listview to specific line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211971/scroll-wpf-listview-to-specific-line)

Comment: You can simply call `ListViewBase.ScrollIntoView(selcetedItem)`.

Comment: Bionic, I am not getting ScrollIntoView property

Comment: Brett Yes you are right